# Magento - Priceless products are not displayed

Tags: magento, product

I work with single and grouped products. I have no problem with my products except those priceless and on demand. They are enabled and visible, but I do not see them, by returning directly against the URL of the product, I see them. 
Is it a configuration issue? 
Thank's.

Comment: Try re-indexing, clear your caches and check again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: there may be conditions that limits the default display products with prices

Comment: CodeJST i tried but whithout result. thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I load products differently,

```
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');

$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
if ($currentCategory){
$currentCategoryId = $currentCategory->getId();

$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addCategoryFilter($currentCategory);
}else{
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
}
```

All enabled products are displayed, priceless products are considered as ' out of stock ' , just replace the text with " On demand ".